# Webscrapping with Rvest - 'Failure when receiving data from the peer'

Tags: r, rvest

I'm having a hard time on get R to read the content of a webpage in order to import the html tables.
Basically, I'm able to access the site on the navigator, but it seems that, as it takes too long to run, the R returns with the error bellow.
The same error doesn't happen with easier to access pages, like [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_highest-grossing_films"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_highest-grossing_films%22), for instance.
I'm eager to try any workaround.
I'm using RStudio 2022.02.1+461
Thanks

````
library(rvest)
library(reprex)

content1 <- read_html(url("http://tjj.xinjiang.gov.cn/tjj/zhhvgh/202203/9b5a616b61c54ff0826e6719fd095f20.shtml", "rb"))
#> Warning in url("http://tjj.xinjiang.gov.cn/tjj/zhhvgh/
#> 202203/9b5a616b61c54ff0826e6719fd095f20.shtml", : URL 'http://
#> tjj.xinjiang.gov.cn/tjj/zhhvgh/202203/9b5a616b61c54ff0826e6719fd095f20.shtml':
#> status was 'Failure when receiving data from the peer'
#> Error in url("http://tjj.xinjiang.gov.cn/tjj/zhhvgh/202203/9b5a616b61c54ff0826e6719fd095f20.shtml", : cannot open the connection to 'http://tjj.xinjiang.gov.cn/tjj/zhhvgh/202203/9b5a616b61c54ff0826e6719fd095f20.shtml'```
````

Comment: Are you within china? Is navigator the same as browser? Which browser and version?

Comment: Hi @QHarr, I'm in South America. The funny thing is that I can access this page easily using the navigator(safari or chrome). I can even inspect html elements and copy the table in html. However, there's seems to be a something prevent R to ready the page...

Comment: In UK I get connection reset by peer i.e. closed using browser (latest Chrome and FF Dev)

Comment: On my end, I can't connect to the website.